# Magento, How to query collection from redis, prior hitting db

Tags: magento, redis, magento-1.9

I have setup redis for magento 1.9. However, I observe that when I query collection, it hitting my db very heavily. Seems like Redis is not caching my db collection, so I wonder do I have to do something when I query collection? Like, first check if collection key exist in redis, if not make db to get collection, then put into redis. The way I obtain collection is this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, array('eq' => $attribute_value))
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->joinTable('review/review_aggregate', 'entity_pk_value = entity_id', array('fhs_reviews_count' => 'reviews_count', 'fhs_rating_summary' => 'rating_summary'), '{{table}}.store_id=1', 'left')
            ->joinTable('multistoreviewpricingpriceindexer/product_index_price', 'entity_id = entity_id', array('final_price' => 'final_price', 'min_price' => 'min_price'), '{{table}}.store_id='.Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(), 'left')
            ->joinField('qty', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left')
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('min_price', array('gt' => 0))                
            ->setPageSize($this->get_prod_count($isMobile))
            ->setCurPage($this->get_cur_page());
```

Comment: Answered, but not sure if you're wondering why the system doesn't cache your collection out of the box, or if you just want to find the way to force-cache your collection. Magento doesn't cache collection results, with Redis enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

The Redis module for Magento only works on sessions and cache data, not as a primary source of storage. If you want to be able to query a collection from Redis, you must store this collection in the cache, and query it after, like this for example :

```php
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$cache = Mage::getSingleton('core/cache');
$key = 'your-custom-key' . $storeId; // feel free to add specific variables to the key

if(! $data = $cache->load($key)) {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, ['eq' => $attribute_value])
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinTable('review/review_aggregate', 'entity_pk_value = entity_id', [
            'fhs_reviews_count' => 'reviews_count',
            'fhs_rating_summary' => 'rating_summary'
        ], '{{table}}.store_id=1', 'left')
        ->joinTable('multistoreviewpricingpriceindexer/product_index_price', 'entity_id = entity_id', [
            'final_price' => 'final_price',
            'min_price'   => 'min_price'
        ], '{{table}}.store_id=' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(), 'left')
        ->joinField('qty', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left')
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('min_price', ['gt' => 0])
        ->setPageSize($this->get_prod_count($isMobile))
        ->setCurPage($this->get_cur_page());

    $data = serialize($collection->getItems()); //or something else
    $cache->save($data, $key, array("homepage_cache"), 60*60*24);
}
else{
    $data = unserialize($data);
}
```